# Not getting passing data from Activity to activity

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I am not getting data which i passed from another Activity using intent.putExtra. Overall it is also not showing errors.
I am new to Android and Kotlin

Activity One

```
        i2.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            var i = Intent(this,Courses::class.java)
            i.putExtra("semester",'2')
            startActivity(i)
        })
```

Activity Two

```
var semester:String? = null
semester = intent.getStringExtra("semester")
```

Not getting any data Just null and also not getting error. I tested it to show using Toast

Comment: `'2'` – That is a `Char` literal, not a `String` literal. Use double quotes for a `String` literal; i.e. `"2"`. Otherwise, if you actually do want to pass a `Char`, retrieve it in the second `Activity` with `getCharExtra()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use Double quotes instead

```
i.putExtra("semester","2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, it should work.

```
i2.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            Intent i = new Intent(this,Courses.class)
            i.putExtra("semester",'2')
            startActivity(i)
        })
```

In second activity try this in OnCreate method:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    savedInstanceState = intent.getExtras();
    char exampleVariable = savedInstanceState.get("semester");
```

Comment: i.putExtra("semester",'2') should be this i.putExtra("semester","2")